# Runtime type checking of constructor options that get passed to super

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, es6-class, tsc

I have this:

```
export class XMLParser extends Transform {

  constructor(opts?: XMLParserOpts, to?: TransformOptions) {

    super(Object.assign({}, to || {}, {objectMode: true}));

  }

}
```

basically I always need `objectMode` to be true. However, what if the user passed in some weird value for `to`? How can I check it to make sure the type is defined an object?

I can let the Transform class do its validation, but I'd rather do that manually and give a custom error message. But the **problem** is, I can't do this:

```
   constructor(opts?: XMLParserOpts, to?: TransformOptions) {

        if(to && typeof to !== 'object'){
          throw new Error('no good bozo');
        }

        super(Object.assign({}, to || {}, {objectMode: true}));

    }
```

how can do what I am looking for? *(TS won't compile if super is not the first call in the constructor).*

Comment: What are the reasons for this 'problem' and why you can't do that? Because this is how it's usually done.

Comment: TS won't compile if super is not the first call in the constructor

Comment: Of course not, this would make the life unbearable. It won't compile if you use this prior to super.

Comment: right, so how do I validate the input then lol

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing to do is something like:

```
  constructor(opts?: XMLParserOpts, to?: TransformOptions) {

        super((function(){

          if(to && typeof to !== 'object'){
              throw new Error('no good bozo');
           }

           return Object.assign({}, to || {}, {objectMode: true})

        })());

    }
```

use cases for IIFEs really do pop up don't they.